# ArchUnit: How to avoid dependency violation to java classes

Tags: java, archunit

I want to verify, that classes within a given package, only refer to classes that reside in the package itself. However I get a violation, telling me that the a class depends on e.g. java.lang.String, which is totally ok for me. Is there a way to ignore the basic java packages?

```java
        @ArchTest
        static final ArchRule zeroDependencyOfDomain = noClasses().that()
            .resideInAPackage("..domain..")
            .should().dependOnClassesThat()
            .resideOutsideOfPackages("..domain..");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to explicitly specify all external packages like `java.`, `javax.`, `com.google.`, `org.apache.` etc. and you just care about project packages, then you can just join two conditions like "domain or external lib".

```
String PROJECT_PACKAGE = "com.myproject..";

DescribedPredicate<JavaClass> domainOrExternalLibPredicate = JavaClass.Predicates.resideInAnyPackage("..domain..")
    .or(JavaClass.Predicates.resideOutsideOfPackage(PROJECT_PACKAGE));

@ArchTest
static final ArchRule zeroDependencyOfDomain = classes().that()
    .resideInAPackage("..domain..")
    .should().onlyDependOnClassesThat()
    .resideInAnyPackage(domainOrExternalLibPredicate);
```

In this caste, external lib is defined as anything outside your `PROJECT_PACKAGE`.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly allow dependencies to java packages:

```
@ArchTest
static final ArchRule zeroDependencyOfDomain = noClasses().that()
    .resideInAPackage("..domain..")
    .should().dependOnClassesThat()
    .resideOutsideOfPackages("..domain..", "java..");
```

You could also use `classes()` and `onlyDependOnClassesThat()`, which a bit easier to read in my opinion:

```
@ArchTest
static final ArchRule zeroDependencyOfDomain = classes().that()
    .resideInAPackage("..domain..")
    .should().onlyDependOnClassesThat()
    .resideInAnyPackage("..domain..", "java..");
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the other answer, I also found no better way yet than this:

```
private static final String[] COMMON_PACKAGES = {
    "java..",
    "javax..",
    "com.google..",
    "org.springframework.."};

@ArchTest
final ArchRule classesInProdutPackageNoOutsideAccess =
    classes()
        .that()
        .resideInAnyPackage(PACKAGE_FOO)
        .should()
        .onlyAccessClassesThat()
        .resideInAnyPackage(commonPackagesAnd(PACKAGE_FOO));


private static String[] commonPackagesAnd(String... packages) {
    return ArrayUtils.addAll(packages, COMMON_PACKAGES);
}
```